# Setting up JMF in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: java, swing, jmf

I have searched high and low trying to figure out how to get this stupid thing working.  I downloaded, and ran, the Windows installer for JMF and set both my `PATH` and `CLASSPATH` environmental variables to the following:

Note this is under User Variables for Admin (My user account name), not System Variables.

```
CLASSPATH

C:\Program Files (x86)\JMF2.1.1e\lib\jmf.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JMF2.1.1e\lib\sound.jar;.;%CLASSPATH%

PATH

C:\Program Files (x86)\JMF2.1.1e\lib;%PATH%
```

However, whenever I go to use the `JMFDiagnostic` Tool Applet on the Oracle website, it also crashes with an error about me not having the right class.  Additionally, when I go into NetBeans 7.3 and try to import one of the packages, it says it does not exist.

Can anyone help a brother out!?  I've blown way to much time working on this!

Answer (score 3):

Try to unistall JMF and reinstall it in C:\JMF2.1.1e\

Here full steps to install JMF on Win 7 :
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2132405

NB : When finish unistalling JMF, don't forget to delete the environment variable named CLASSPATH in user variables (if it does not removed automatically).

Answer (score 0):

if you have 64 bit JDK, it wont work. bcz JMF is only available for 32 bit platform. So you need to install  32bit JDK as well. (and to avoid JDK configuration issues, better uninstall the 64bit JDK)

Answer (score 0):

*If a java program using JMF working in Windows XP and not working in Windows 7, here is the solution:*

1. Install JMF on your Windows 7 PC normally. Suppose your JMF installation dir is : C:\Program Files\JMF2.1.1e.
2. Create a file **C:\WINDOWS\java.jmfdir**, open .jmfdir file and write following line in this file
   **C:\PROGRA~1\JMF21~1.1E\lib**

Gurmeet Singh

Answer (score 0):

correction :   C:\WINDOWS\java\jmfdir and not C:\WINDOWS\java.jmfdir

......... so you must create manual the java Directory in Windows Directory and then create manual the jmfdir file in Java directory  and then write in jmfdir file this Path :

C:\PROGRA~1\JMF21~1.1E\lib